# Approach for Qt Parsing of Bencode

Tags: c++, qt, parsing, lexical-analysis

I am creating a simple [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) [Bencode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode) parser as an exercise to acquaint myself with the [QString](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html) class.

My current approach creates a Bencode object with behaves like a scanner and parses by incrementally advancing a string pointer (`pos`), resulting in code that looks like this (`bEncoded` is a Bencode [QString](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html)):

```
void Bencode::parseInteger() {
    qDebug() << "Parsing an Integer";

    if(bEncoded.at(pos) != intChar) {
        qDebug() << "No leading i for integer";
        return;
    }
    pos++;
    QString buf;
    if(bEncoded.at(pos).isNumber() || bEncoded.at(pos) == negChar) {
        buf.append(bEncoded.at(pos));
        pos++;
    }
    while(bEncoded.at(pos).isNumber()) {
        buf.append(bEncoded.at(pos));
        pos++;
    }
    if(!bEncoded.at(pos).unicode() == 'e') {
        qDebug() << "No training e for integer";
        return;
    }
    pos++;
    qDebug("Integer: %i", buf.toInt());
}
```

I'm wondering if this is a concise approach.  It seems like I'm abusing `QString::at()` and `QChar==`.  As I look at it, I'm thinking RegEx's could be more concise, but figured I would ask for some opinions here as well.

So - how could this approach be improved?

All code here: https://github.com/jif/Bencode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I found a somewhat less memory-intensive approach.  Instead of creating QChar's all over the place and doing comparisons, I can use QString::mid() to extract substrings.  For example, the integer parser becomes:

```
int Bencode::parseInteger() {
    qDebug() << "Parsing an Integer";

    // Validate the integer
    if(currentChar() != intChar) {
        qDebug() << "No leading i for integer";
        return 0;
    }
    pos++;
    int len = bEncoded.indexOf(endChar,pos)-pos;
    if(len>0) {
        int intBuf = bEncoded.mid(pos,len).toInt();
        qDebug("Integer: %i", intBuf);
        pos = pos+len+1;
        return intBuf;
    } else {
        qDebug("Integer sytax error at %i",pos);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Looks more concise to me :)